# How to make this UILabel move the email address to the next Line?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, line-breaks

I have a simple `UILabel` that is printing text as follows:

```
John Doe sent a message to blahblah-
blah@blahblah.com
```

Thus, the email address here : `blahblah-blah@blahblah.com` is being cut and partially displayed on the next line. What do I need to do to make it display as :

```
John Doe sent a message to 
blahblah-blah@blahblah.com
```

?

I already have the following :

```
self.mailLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakModeByWordWrapping;
self.mailLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

The string in question is :

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You sent a message to %@", emailAddress];
```

What should I do here? Remember, the name can be long and hence, adding a line break in the string won't work because I don't want the following case :

```
Jonathon Dawson sent a message
to 
blahblah-blah@blahblah.com
```

which should be

```
Jonathon Dawson sent a message
to blahblah-blah@blahblah.com
```

Comment: What do you want to see in the long name case? There isn't enough room to get the email all on the second line so it either has to be cut up or on its own line.

Comment: If I forcibly add a line break, then in the second case as you can see, the email will be down and the second line will only contain `to`. In this case, since the text fits, it should be put in on the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **ZWNBSP**(Zero-width no-break space) characters to the left and to the right of - (hyphen, aka dash) symbol:

```
self.mailLabel.text = [self.mailLabel.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"\u2060-\u2060"];
```

**Remarks:**

*U+2060* - Zero-width no-break space Unicode character prevents any line breaks that may be inserter to wrap the word before and after it. As soon as `UILabel` (as well as other text controls in Cocoa) respects Unicode, you will get text without undesired line breaks.

Wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_no-break_space

Answer (score 1):

```
self.mailLabel = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"You sent a message to\n%@"];
```

You use \n to make a new line.
Also, make sure you set the numberOfLines to 2 on the label.