# Set custom word boundaries in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

I'm displaying a multiline NSAttributedString on a UILabel, I have a problem with the line breaking. When wrapping a word that ends with a plus sign ('+'), the UILabel breaks the line before the '+' sign.

I tried every lineBreakMode available but no matter what I do, if the last word of the line ends with '+', it'll break before it.

For example, using the text "My name is Fred and C++ is my language"

The UILabel will render in two lines like this:

```
"My name is Fred and C"
"++ is my language"
```

In this article on Apple's documentation ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsParagraphBreaks.html)) says:

> The text system determines word boundaries in a language-specific manner according to Unicode Standard Annex #29 with additional customization for locale as described in that document. On OS X, Cocoa presents APIs related to word boundaries, such as the NSAttributedString methods doubleClickAtIndex: and nextWordFromIndex:forward:, but **you cannot modify the way the word-boundary algorithms themselves work**.

Any ideas?

Comment: i have tried the same scenario in interface builder but it is behaving fine, for you it is behaving like above programmatically?

Comment: Since the number of lines varies, I'm setting the attributed text and the preferredMaxLayoutWidth programmatically. 

The attributes I use are: NSFontAttributeName, NSForegroundColorAttributeName and NSKernAttributeName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a Unicode U+2060 WORD JOINER between each of the visible characters in `C++`.  You can use `\u2060` in a string literal, or you can use the Unicode Hex Input keyboard to type it as <kbd>⌥2060</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks Rob! That did it!
Thanks to that, I also found this case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393904/how-to-make-this-uilabel-move-the-email-address-to-the-next-line